# Android Code NPE Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse

We are trying to make a nutrition application for the semester project.

When try to run the program on the emulator, the apk file runs and closes down immediately with error.

java code :

```
package com.example.nutripro;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

 public class BMI extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText hgtf;
EditText wgtf;
EditText bmi;
Button calc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hgtf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    wgtf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    bmi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    calc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new ClickButton ());        

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

private class ClickButton implements Button.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        float hg,wg,sh,res; 
        hg=Float.parseFloat(hgtf.getText().toString());
        wg=Float.parseFloat(wgtf.getText().toString());
        sh=hg*hg;
        res=sh/wg;
        bmi.setText(" "+"Your calculated body mass index is:"+res);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bmi, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
  }

  }
```

fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nutripro.BMI$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="BMI Calculator"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Calculate your Body Mass Index"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nutripro"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nutripro.BMI"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat :

```
05-07 03:14:31.380: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nutripro/com.example.nutripro.BMI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can someone advise us to solve this issue ??

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question and add the exception from LogCat?

Comment: I have added the exception from logcat.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear - please add the complete stacktrace that comes after the exception; it should have file names,method names and line numbers. Could you also mark in your post the line numbers that exist in your files, so that we can see exactly what lines are participating in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `findViewById()` and `setOnClickListener()` from activity `onCreate()` to fragment `onCreateView()` since the views you operate on are in the fragment layout and not activity layout:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, false);
hgtf=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
wgtf=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
bmi=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
calc=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
calc.setOnClickListener(new ClickButton ());
```